# Not working --playlist-start option of youtube-dl script

Tags: youtube-dl

[Windows 10]

I have a video playlist URL having 128 items and I have already downloaded 25 videos from same playlist URL.
Now I want to download remaining videos starting from 26 index But I am not able to download it using --palylist-start option.

When I is use --palylist-start 26 option.
It doesn't start from 26 index instead download start from index 1 and also it shows total videos 102 (that means 128-26=102).

I don't understand what's happening here.

I have tried like:

```
youtube-dl --playlist-start 26 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2E1npU5xmk&list=PLSoOtQkDh8ByH7x6eQfjVt09V9GJMxL2Z"
```

Ouput:

````
C:\Users\RohitG\Downloads\ffmpeg\bin>youtube-dl --playlist-start 26 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2E1npU5xmk&list=PLSoOtQkDh8ByH7x6eQfjVt09V9GJMxL2Z"
[youtube:playlist] Downloading playlist PLSoOtQkDh8ByH7x6eQfjVt09V9GJMxL2Z - add --no-playlist to just download video Q2E1npU5xmk
[youtube:playlist] PLSoOtQkDh8ByH7x6eQfjVt09V9GJMxL2Z: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Photoshop Tutorials
[youtube:playlist] PLSoOtQkDh8ByH7x6eQfjVt09V9GJMxL2Z: Downloading page #1
[youtube:playlist] playlist Photoshop Tutorials: Downloading 102 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 102
[youtube] -DLZbLKUYA0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] -DLZbLKUYA0: Downloading video info webpage
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: Galaxy Portrait Effect _ Photoshop Tutorial--DLZbLKUYA0.f137.mp4
[download]   5.9% of 34.10MiB at  1.87MiB/s ETA 00:17
ERROR: Interrupted by user

C:\Users\RohitG\Downloads\ffmpeg\bin>
```[![you can see below output][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U52NE.png
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually downloading them correctly, just removing first 25 items from list, So first item in list what you are loading is actually 26th.
Also as you can see from log, name of video you are loading is "Galaxy Portrait Effect", so it's not first but 26th, as expected.

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thank you so much.